I get repository errors when I launch the Discover store does anyone know how to fix this?
W: Repositories should provide a clear-signed InRelease file, but none found at http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/impish-security/InRelease.
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
W: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
W: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.


The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security Release' does not have a Release file.
W: https://hub.unity3d.com/linux/repos/deb/dists/stable/InRelease: Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring (/etc/apt/trusted.gpg), see the DEPRECATION section in apt-key(8) for details.

This question is similar to: What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

You've tagged that you're using 24.10; but your error message is for impish or 21.10 which is EOL and unsupported.  It'll provide you with nothing of value, as impish has been EOL for years now!

Ubuntu 21.10 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu.  https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/07/19/ubuntu-21-10-impish-indri-end-of-life-reached-on-july-14-2022/   https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

the reason for having this repository was to install something needed to make unityhub work on 24.10 since unityhub only supports ubuntu 20.04 because of that file, which i made unityhub work by installing the package from 21.10

This question is similar to: apt-key deprecation warning when updating system: "Key is stored in legacy trusted.gpg keyring". If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
